# Laravel Validation should fail yet getting SQL exception error of "out of range"

Tags: laravel

- Laravel 5.5
- 10.1.32-MariaDB

I am QA'ing some entries where I have the following rule:

`'required|numeric|min:0|max:9999999999999999.99999999'`

That column has a float type of `double(16,8)`, now if I insert the number above + 1 which should fail validation and redirect with errors, I get a MySQL error: `Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column`

Am I missing something in my validation rule?

Comment: Your database column range is less than you are entering in validations

Comment: integers and strings have max length read about them and do validations accordingly.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad - this `9999999999999999.99999999` is a floating (16,8), exactly as DB, or maybe you weren't clear enough by what you meant.

Comment: Read this may be it can help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Max validator works only with integer values:

Docs for [Max](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-max) validation rule:

> Strings, numerics, arrays, and files are evaluated in the same fashion as the size rule.

[Size](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-size) rule description:

> ... For numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. ...

In your case validator simply ignores the `max` validation rule.

Perhaps you would like to create [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Comment: This is not the answer.

Comment: The question is: "Am I missing something in my validation rule?".
The answer: yes, you are missing that `max` validator works only with integers. You should write your own validator to test this particular testcase.